# Expect script is not working with SFTP with proxy command

Tags: shell, unix, proxy, sftp, expect

I am trying to execute SFTP command with proxy option, but it is giving error. Script sample is as below

##### Start

```
sftpCommand="sftp -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o "ProxyCommand=/usr/bin/nc --proxy-type http --proxy 192.168.20.98:3128 --proxy-auth pxuser:Password@1 %h %p" -oPort=22 user-sftp2@202.89.99.20"

/usr/bin/expect << EOD
                set timeout -1
                
                spawn /bin/sh -c $sftpCommand
                expect {
                        "*?assword:*" { 
                            send "$sftpPassword\r"
                        }
                        "*>*" {  
                            send "put $datewise_dir $remoteDir\r"
                        }
                        "*>*" {
                            send "bye\r"
                        }
                    }
EOD
```

#### End

above script is giving error like

```
line 6: {--proxy-type}: command not found
spawn /bin/sh -c
/bin/sh: -c: option requires an argument
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first line defining `sftpCommand` you use double quotes `"` inside a string which is itself enclosed in double quotes - this nesting will not work.  You can fix this by changing the outer quotes to single ones `'`, i.e.

```
sftpCommand='sftp -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o "ProxyCommand=/usr/bin/nc --proxy-type http --proxy 192.168.20.98:3128 --proxy-auth pxuser:Password@1 %h %p" -oPort=22 user-sftp2@202.89.99.20'
```